# how to convert matlab to C using MATLAB coder

Tags: c, matlab, matlab-coder

I want to convert matlab code to C code using MATLAB coder, but is doesn't work well.

I tried to below matlab code .. and build using MATLAB coder

```
 function  example()

     recObj = audiorecorder(44100,16,1); 
     disp('Start speaking.');
     recordblocking(recObj, 5);
     disp('End of Recording.');

      play(recObj);
```

But there are some errors. like..

> > coder -build ex1.prj 
> >         ??? The 'audiorecorder' class does not support code generation.

```
  Error in ==> example Line: 2 Column: 10
  Code generation failed: Open error report.
```

so, I tried to delete audiorecorder function, but it didn't work also.

I don't know What problem in these code. 
How do I do?
Please help.

Comment: It is simply not possible to generate code for the audiorecorder, if you need an audio recorder you have to reimplement the functionallity in c.

Comment: This question seems to be related to your previous one (deploy to android). I think it's the wrong way to deploy multimedia related code from matlab to android, because you have to deal with the android api and permissions. What is your plan?

Comment: Yeah, Actually I want to use matlab code on java(deploy to android). And I find one option that convert matlab to C code and use that C code for deploying to android. But it also doesn't work well.

Comment: Yeah, Actually I want to use matlab code on java(deploy to android). And I find one option that convert matlab to C code and use that C code for deploying to android. But Now, I failed to covert matlab code to C code. Actually, the code that I wrote for recording using matlab is just example, even though I tried to covert just disp fuction [function  example() disp('Start speaking.');] to C code , but it also doesn't work. How do I do ? Please help.

Comment: I think you simply chose the wrong programming language, do you really need to use matlab?

Comment: Yeah, Actaully I already realize algorithms with matlab, So I want to reuse my code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every MATLAB function can be converted to C code.

For a list of supported function see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation--alphabetical-list.html).

If you wish to use MATLAB functions that are not on the list, you should write your own version in MATLAB (if possible, in your case I doubt it) or in C.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be helpful for deploying to Android, but there is the [dsp.AudioRecorder](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.audiorecorder-class.html) System Object that supports C code generation and allows for some audio recording.  The resulting code can be run on systems where MATLAB is installed.

Another option is to write your computational algorithm in MATLAB Coder compliant code and do the audio capture, user interaction and the like using Android APIs.  You could then just pass the captured audio data to the generated native code for processing.  I've seen a similar approach taken with image processing where the Android API was used to capture images which were then sent to C code generated with MATLAB Coder for processing.